# golang google storage copy error

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I get an error when trying to install google cloud storage SDK for Golang.

```
go get -u cloud.google.com/go/storage

# cloud.google.com/go/storage
../../../../cloud.google.com/go/storage/copy.go:81: cannot use 
res.TotalBytesRewritten (type int64) as type uint64 in argument to c.ProgressFunc
../../../../cloud.google.com/go/storage/copy.go:81: cannot use 
res.ObjectSize (type int64) as type uint64 in argument to c.ProgressFunc
```

Has this happened to anyone else? How did you resolve this issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I got it too looks like some latest commit broke this library...

Comment: Now it seems to be OK again - deployment is working and issue on github for this problem was closed

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, but there was a commit that broke the install. I filed a Github issue and they seemed to have fixed it. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/issues/266